# Problem with indent in enumeration of paralist

Tags: lists, indentation, enumerate

I have the following enumeration:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paralist}
\begin{document}
\begin{compactenum}[i.]
\item foo
\item foo
\item foo
\item foo
\item foo
\item foo
\item foo
\item foo
\end{compactenum}
\end{document}
```

The text after the 8. item is indented more then any other item-text (apparently because "viii." is pretty long).

How can I fix this? I would probably like to align the item-symbols somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `neveradjust` option for `paralist` package:

```
 \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[neveradjust]{paralist}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{compactenum}[i.]
    \item foo
    \item foo
    \item foo
    \item foo
    \item foo
    \item foo
    \item foo
    \item foo
    \item foo
    \end{compactenum}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, i like that. do you know if/how i can align the items to the left? apparently theres the optional argument `flushleft`, which works, but not together with `neveradjust`.

Comment: No problem with `\usepackage[flushleft, neveradjust]{paralist}` or `\usepackage[flushright, neveradjust]{paralist}`

Comment: hmm, i thought i just tried that, but apparently i didn't. anyways it works, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use the `enumitem` package: the  `noitemsep` option of a list makes `\itemsep` equal to `baselineskip`, but there is a separation from the surrounding text, and  `nosep` suppresses all vertical spacing. You can have the labels left or right aligned. Here is how to do it in both cases, and a comparison with the result of the `compactenum` environment:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar, noheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{paralist}
\renewcommand*\theenumi{(\roman{enumi})}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\begin {enumerate} [(i),nosep, align = left, leftmargin =* , widest* = 8]%
\item An item
\item An item
\item An item
\item An item
\item An item
\item An item
\item An item
\item An item
\item An item
\item An item
\end {enumerate}
Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\begin {enumerate} [(i),nosep]%
\item An item \\ Text text text text text text text text
\item An item
\item An item
\item An item
\item An item
\item An item
\item An item
\item An item
\item An item
\item An item
\end {enumerate}
Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\begin{compactenum}
\item An item \\ Text text text text text text text text
\item An item
\item An item
\item An item
\item An item
\item An item
\item An item
\item An item
\item An item
\item An item
\end{compactenum}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the comprehensive answer. but though this is just as good, i want to/have to use `paralist`, which doesnt seem to like `enumitem`.

Comment: As far as I know everything `compactenum` does can be done with the `nosep` option of enumitem (except the text alignment that I've just tested). See my edited answer to compare.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
\begin{compactenum}[i.]\labelwidth=4em
```

or use package `enumitem` then you can control it by optional arguments.

Comment: thanks. but now the 8. label sticks out to the left over the edge of the text, which isn't very nice.