# Item indent with paralist

Tags: indentation, paralist

I have problem with paralist and indent please see example:

[image]

The code I'm using is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[flushleft,neveradjust]{paralist}
\usepackage[pangram]{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[ {[}1{]} ]
    \item \Blindtext[1][1]
    \item \Blindtext[1][1]
    \item \Blindtext[1][1]
    \item \Blindtext[1][1]
    \item \Blindtext[1][1]
    \item \Blindtext[1][1]
    \item \Blindtext[1][1]
    \item \Blindtext[1][1]
    \item \Blindtext[1][1]
    \item \Blindtext[1][1]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

And anyone please help, how to remove this space ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described  in the answer of @Herbert [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/176142/120578), you can adjust the label width like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[flushleft,neveradjust]{paralist}
\usepackage[pangram]{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[ {[}1{]} ]\labelwidth=2.5em
    \item \Blindtext[1][1]
    \item \Blindtext[1][1]
    \item \Blindtext[1][1]
    \item \Blindtext[1][1]
    \item \Blindtext[1][1]
    \item \Blindtext[1][1]
    \item \Blindtext[1][1]
    \item \Blindtext[1][1]
    \item \Blindtext[1][1]
    \item \Blindtext[1][1]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Another option for you is to use `alwaysadjust` and specify with a second optional argument (`[10]`) the wider item:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[flushleft,alwaysadjust]{paralist}
\usepackage[pangram]{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[ {[}1{]} ][10]
    \item \Blindtext[1][1]
    \item \Blindtext[1][1]
    \item \Blindtext[1][1]
    \item \Blindtext[1][1]
    \item \Blindtext[1][1]
    \item \Blindtext[1][1]
    \item \Blindtext[1][1]
    \item \Blindtext[1][1]
    \item \Blindtext[1][1]
    \item \Blindtext[1][1]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I am using `paralist` for around 7-8 years, but never knew that there was a second optional argument to denote the widest item.  I used this yesterday to get the label width of the `(viii)`th item right in a nested `compactenum` with the package !  Cheers to your answer !~!

Comment: Thanks for your comment @ParthaD.